# Error while loading HTML pages to confluence :Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python

I have an HTML page  . I want to create page in confluence and upload the content in that page.
I am able to create  a page if static content is passed in variable "f".
but when passing the HTML page as the value of "f"  . i am getting below error :
TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable

Looks like HTML needs to be converted to different format .I am not sure how to resolve this.

> **---Content of html file
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <body>
>
> <h1>My First Heading</h1>
> <p>My first paragraph.</p>
>
> </body>
> </html>**
> ```

```
---code

import yaml
from atlassian import Confluence
import urllib, mimetypes
import  requests
import codecs,json

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://confluence.com',
    username='12344',  # of system where this page would open
    password='abcd')

####reading HTML file
f=codecs.open("sample.html", 'r')
print (f.read())



# Create page from scratch
status = confluence.create_page('ABCD' ,#space,
                       'Report',#title
                        f ,#'This is the body',#body,
                       parent_id=123456,### this is the pageid of the page under which new page will be created
                       type='page',
                       representation='storage',
                       editor='v2')

print(status)
```

Comment: `f` is a file descriptor. Remove `print(f.read())` and put `f.read()` in place of `f` in your `create_page` call

Comment: Thanks mark. code ran perfectly but HTML content didnt loaded in new page. any idea why this may happen

Comment: Did you remove the `print(f.read())`?  A second `f.read()` would read nothing because the file has already reached the end.  Alternatively, use `content = f.read()`, `print(content)`, then use `content` in `create_page()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` is a file descriptor.  Instead, read the content into a variable and use that:

```py
with open("sample.html") as f:
    content = f.read()
print(content)

status = confluence.create_page('ABCD',
                                'Report',
                                content,
                                parent_id=123456,
                                type='page',
                                representation='storage',
                                editor='v2')
```

Comment: Hi  @Mark Tolonen, Thanks for the response. After doing these change , i m getting below error:
Error parsing xhtml: Unrecognized XML directive; expected CDATA or comment